# Output two files when rendering an animation

Tags: rendering

I'm working on rendering out my first 3D animation from Blender!

It is a scene that I'm rendering with a transparent sky that I'll composite in After Effects later. I'm outputting to Radiance HDR so I can do HDR toning in Photoshop. . .

So, what I've done so far is render a few frames, then save them first as a Radiance HDR and then as a PNG. I use the HDR for my image data and pull the alpha channel out of the PNG, the problem I'm having is that when I render my animation I don't have the option to output both filetypes.

Is there a way to output more than one filetype while rendering an animation?

Or maybe there is something else that I'm missing all together, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sure there's some way to render two filetypes at once, but I would recommend simply rendering out one first, then converting it to another type afterwards using something like ImageMagick. For example, to convert a bunch of png's to jpeg's, you would simply type: `mogrify -format jpg *.png`

Comment: That's a thought... I'll keep that in mind, Matt's suggestion does what I was really wanting, so I'll just stick with it for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is a way! The Compositor has a [File Output](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Output) node, of which you can have more than one! This node should allow you to save as many versions of your image as you need, at whatever stage of the compositing process, and with whichever passes you need.

Comment: I'll try that, I've never messed with compositor nodes yet... Will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Cool! BlenderGuru has a tutorial that you might find helpful: http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/introduction-to-the-compositor/ Good luck!

Comment: I figured it out... At least what I tried worked pretty good, but I'll watch the video you sent as well. Thanks a Million!

Comment: While you can add more than one File Output node you can also configure more than one output setting within each File Output node. Adjustments can be made in the properties panel (N) with the File Output node selected.

Comment: I did not know that! Awesome!

Comment: Thanks! What about the annoying output option in the panel? I already have all my outputs desired in the node editor. Leaving that blank stops my rendering; writing something there is weird too.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean the output section of the render settings, where you normally set output? If that's what you mean, just use that like another file output node. You don't get to control at what point it outputs an image, but you can still save out the final image from there. If it really is totally worthless (sometimes compositing behaves strangely), I'd just choose the highest compression ratio and put them all in a folder you can delete easily.

Answer (score 2):

If you select **OpenEXR** (which is also an HDR and multilayer format) as the render file format, you will have the option to save a JPEG preview automatically.

Comment: I just figured that out... I'm just exporting as OpenEXR now and using the embedded alpha channel.